# Rfc2898DeriveBytes and TripleDes

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography

I have now learnt that `PasswordDeriveBytes` is deprecated in favor of `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`.
Looking up `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` on MSDN. There is a code example that uses `TripleDES`.
But `TripleDes` is older and weaker than `AES`. Why have they seemingly taken one step forward and one step back?
Can one just replace the `TripleDes` with `AES` or is `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` intrinsically linked to `TripleDes`?

Comment: Your choice of KDF and your choice of cipher are orthogonal. Just use it with AES (MSDN examples typically suck and don't demonstrate good coding practice).

Comment: [Modern Examples of Symmetric Authenticated Encryption of a string. C#](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10366194/637783)

Answer (score 5):

A password based KDF simply turns a password+salt into a sequence of bytes which you can use as key, or store as password hash.

It's in no way linked to your choice of cipher, you can use PBKDF2 together with AES. One minor issue is how much data you read from PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA-1. I recommend only reading 20 bytes, and using a separate hash to increase their size when that's needed.

There is no reason to follow MSDN examples. They often do not follow good coding practices. Just because they use 3DES doesn't mean you should.

Answer (score 1):

`PBKDF2` (`Rfc2898DeriveBytes`) is used to derive a key from a password (Key Derivation Function), the key length it generates and what you do subsequently are your choice, so use `PBKDF2` to generate they key and use which ever symmetric cipher you like. To answer your question, there is no intrinsic link.